# How to add sets to the dataframe by loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have some sets which contain numbers and named as k1,k2,k3,k4 ... k20. Now  I want to make a dataframe base on them. How can I do it will loop? My present thought is

```
k1 <- c(1,2,3)
k2 <- c(2,3,4)
k3 <- c(4,5,6)
...
k20<- c(3,4,5)
i <- 1
df1 <- c()
which (i <= parameter){
df1 <- dataframe(df1,ki)
i = i+1
}
#What I want to do is build different size of dataframe by given a parameter
#when parameter = 15 then df1 <- dataframe (k1,k2,k3...,k15)
# when parameter = 12 then df1 <- dataframe (k1,k2,k3...,k12)
```

But it did not work. Could anyone give me some tips on how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Any reason why `rbind` doesn't work?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan mean problem is ki do not work

Comment: What is `ki` in this case?

Comment: I think they are looking for `data.frame(var = paste0("k",1:15))`

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry I did not make it clean. I have edited my question now. Please tell me if I make it clean this time. thank you

Comment: @JakeKaupp Thank you for answering me. I have tried but your method can only get a dataframe which contain only character k1,k2,...k15 no the numbers of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls` with `pattern` to get objects which start with `k` and then subset the objects using `1:n`, use `mixedsort` to sort the vectors according to their names (to avoid `k11` being picked up before `k2`) and put all this one dataframe.

```
library(gtools)

n = 5
object_name <- mixedsort(ls(pattern = "^k"))[1:n]
data.frame(mget(object_name))

#  k1 k2 k3 k4 k5
#1  1  2  4  3  3
#2  2  3  5  4  4
#3  3  4  6  5  5

n = 2
object_name <- mixedsort(ls(pattern = "^k"))[1:n]
data.frame(mget(object_name))

#  k1 k2
#1  1  2
#2  2  3
#3  3  4
```

**data**

```
k1 <- c(1,2,3)
k2 <- c(2,3,4)
k3 <- c(4,5,6)
k4 <- c(3, 4, 5)
k5 <- c(3,4,5)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you tell me the meaning of ls? And how can I control the number of ki I want to add into the df?

Comment: @Codezy `ls` actually returns characters strings of all the objects in your environment. just type `ls()` in your console and see what you get. With `ls(pattern = "^k")` it will return objects which only start with `k`.

Comment: ok actually I want to make a function and control the size of my dataframe by giving the parameter. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Codezy I am not sure if I understand you completely. What do you mean by control the size of my dataframe by giving the parameter ?

Comment: I got 20 sets which are k1 to k20, I want to make different size dataframes to only contain for example k1 to k5 or k1 to k16.

Comment: Can you update your post with relevant example? Currently, it does not show what you want to do.

Comment: @Codezy I have updated the answer. See if it works for your case.